# How to manage multiple non nested Models in a rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

i have two tables(adverb,word) and two controllers(adverbs,words).i want to have one form to add and edit the records of two tables.
adverb controller:

```
class AdverbsController < ApplicationController
  def new
         @adverb=Adverb.new
  end
  def create
    @adverb=Adverb.create(params[:adverb])

    if   @adverb.save
      redirect_to :action => 'index'
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
  def index
        @adverb =Adverb.find(:all)
  end
  def edit
        @adverb =Adverb.find(params[:id])
  end
  def update

    if @adverb.update_attributes(params[:adverb])
      redirect_to :action => 'index'
    else
      redirect_to :action => 'edit'
    end
  end
end
```

and words controller:

```
class WordsController < ApplicationController
  def new
         @word=Word.new

  end
  def create
    @word=Word.create(params[:word])

    if @word.save
      redirect_to :action => 'index'
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
  def index
        @word=Word.find(:all)
  end
  def edit
        @word=Word.find(params[:id])
  end
  def update

    if @word.update_attributes(params[:word])
      redirect_to :action => 'index'
    else
      redirect_to :action => 'edit'
    end
  end
end
```

I use Partial form

```
<html>


<div id="tabs">
     <ul>
       <li><a href="#tabs-1">word</a> </li>
       <li><a href="#tabs-2">Adverb</a> </li>
     </ul>
     <div id="tabs-1">
       <table >
        <tr>
          <td align="right">
            Artikel :
          </td>
          <td align="center">
            <%= w.label :Artikel ,'der' %><%= w.radio_button :Artikel,'der',:checked =>false%>
            <%= w.label :Artikel ,'die' %><%= w.radio_button :Artikel,'die',:checked =>true %>
            <%= w.label :Artikel ,'das' %><%= w.radio_button :Artikel,'das',:checked =>false %>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right">
            Neues Wort:
          </td>
          <td>
             <%= w.text_field :Name ,:size => '31*45'%>
          </td>
        </tr>

         <tr>
          <td align="right">
            Synonome :
          </td>
          <td>
             <%= w.text_field :syn ,:size => '31*45'%>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td align="right">
            Bedeutung :
          </td>
          <td>
             <%=  w.text_area :bedeutung , :size =>'30*45' %>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right">
              Beispiel :
          </td>
          <td>
            <%= w.text_field :beispiel ,:size => '31*45' %>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
             Kommentar:
          </td>
          <td>
            <%= w.text_area :kommentar ,:size =>'30*45' %>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="center">
              <%= w.submit submit_lable %>

          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
     </div>

       <div id="tabs-2">
               <%= fields_for (@adverb) do |av| %>
               <table>
                 <tr>
                   <td align="right">
                     Adverb :
                   </td>
                   <td>
                      <%= av.text_field :name %>
                   </td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                   <td align="right">
                     Bedeutung :
                   </td>
                   <td>
                     <%=  av.text_field :bedeutung %>
                   </td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                   <td align="right">
                     Synonome :
                   </td>
                   <td>
                      <%= av.text_field :syn %>
                   </td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                   <td>
                        <%= w.submit submit_lable %>
                   </td>
                 </tr>
               </table>

              <% end %>
             </div>
   </div>
</html>
```

and im my new.html.erb :

```
<html>
<body>
<%= form_for(@word) do |w| %>
<%= render :partial => 'form',:locals => {:w =>w,:submit_lable =>'mmmm'} %>
<% end %>
</body>
</html>
```

but an error occured:

```
NoMethodError in Words#new

Showing /home/babak/kurs/app/views/words/_form.erb where line #197 raised:

undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
```

how can i solve my problem?
thank you for your helps

Comment: If your problem is the form, and the error says that, maybe you could add the form to the question

Answer (score 0):

I assume this exception is raised when getting the new action of the words controller. In your _form.html.erb, you have the following code:

```
<%= fields_for (@adverb) do |av| %>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">
        Adverb :
      </td>
      <td>
        <%= av.text_field :name %>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">
        Bedeutung :
      </td>
      <td>
        <%=  av.text_field :bedeutung %>
      </td>
    ...
  </table>
<%= end %>
```

I see nowhere in your new action of the words controller where @adverb is declared. Instance variables default to nil, which is why you see this error.

Comment: thank's,I know but how can i manage multiple non related Models from one controller? does it posible?

Comment: Well one thing to get this to work would be to simply replace @adverb with Adverb.new. You could also split the form down into smaller partials, and do something like this: `render :partial => 'adverb_form if @adverb'`. Good luck.